# How can I convert the Taks in a Tasks list into PDF documents?

Tags: task-list, pdf, document-converter

In order to document what happened on a project and why those decisions were made my customers needs to turn the tasks on a task list into documents, preferably PDFs. For now I only have to convert the current version of the tasks, and it could be implemented as a batch job that should be executed then the project is completed.

Any ideas about how to approach this challenge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few libraries out in the wild that create PDF files from ASP.NET pages.

What you could do is have an application page that displays your tasks in the form of a datatable or SPGridView, and uses one of those PDF libraries to write that page to a PDF.

Here's an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx

Here's a link to Muhimbi's blog which uses another tool which can be implemented in a workflow on an uploaded document, could be manipulated in a way to convert a page generated on the fly perhaps:

http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/04/using-pdf-converter-from-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reference James.

You can perhaps merge the list data into an MS-Word file before PDF conversion [as described here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/09/inserting-sharepoint-list-data-into-pdf.html). You can do this in combination with a workflow.

The latest version also supports [HTML to PDF conversion](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html) so you could create an HTML string on the fly and send that to the converter or convert the item's detail page directly.